# Distribution induced by a function

Tags: distribution-theory

We are given $F(x) = |2x+1|, x \in \mathbb{R}$

How to determine whether $$[F|_{(0, \infty)}] \in \mathcal{D}'((0, \infty))$$

$$[F|_{(- \infty, 0)}] \in \mathcal{D}'((- \infty, 0))$$

are regular distributions?

When it comes to the first one, we have $F|_{(0, \infty)}(x) = 2x+1$ and this function is continuous, so it is locally integrable, so it induces a regular distribution.

But when it comes to the second one, we have that on interval $(- \infty, - \frac{1}{2})$ , $F(x) = -2x-1$ and on $[ - \frac{1}{2}, 0)$, $F(x) = 2x+1$.

So we need to determine whether in the second case, we can write down the distribution as

$$<F, \varphi> = \int_{\mathbb{R}} F(x) \varphi (x) dx $$ for a test function $\varphi \in D(\mathbb{R})$, that is a smooth function with compact support.

Could you help me with that?

Comment: It is not continuous but still locally integrable...

Comment: Because it is continuous, right? So the distribution is regular in both cases?

Comment: what matters is local integrability. So even a discontinuous function that is locally integrable such as a step function still defines a regular distribution

Comment: Could you calculate the integral in the second case?

Comment: Yes take $[a,b]$ to be the compact support of $\phi$ that contains $-1/2$ and cut the integral in two below $1/2$ and above $1/2$

Comment: $\int_{\mathbb{R}} F(x) \phi (x) dx = \int_{[a,b]} F(x) \phi (x) dx = \int_a ^{-1/2} (-2x-1) \phi (x) dx + \int_{-1/2}^b (2x+1) \phi (x) dx$ - is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes exactly what I mean

Comment: Ok, summarizing, we have that while integraling $F(x)\phi (x)$ for $\phi$ with appropriate support, we split the integral into two and each of the integrals is finite, so this means that the distribution is regular. Is that correct?